# Create a numerical sequence?

Tags: r

I have a dataset in R with multiple columns. One of them is called "codification" yes for identification codes starting with "WC". For example WC1, WC2, WC3...

However, I have detected that there are duplicates. Specifically 7 duplicates. I have detected this with the following code.

```
duplicates=sum(duplicated(Dataframe$cod))
```

Well, I want to assign a new code to avoid duplicate codes. The new code must be an unused value (values higher than the maximum numeric value contained in codes) and keeping "WC" in front of the
numerical sequence.  I have tried to do it in the following way but I am not convinced. Any ideas?

```
library(stringr)
max.code <- max( as.numeric( str_sub(codes, 3) )) + 1
new.codes <- seq( max.code, max.code + N-1 )
codes[idx] <- paste("CS", new.codes, sep="")
codes[idx]
```

Answer (score 0):

Would this work?

```
Dataframe = data.frame("Values"=runif(1000))
Dataframe$codification = paste0("WC", seq_along(1:nrow(Dataframe)))
head(Dataframe)
      Values codification
1 0.8530932          WC1
2 0.4727743          WC2
3 0.5412880          WC3
4 0.8054319          WC4
5 0.9324827          WC5
6 0.8962318          WC6

tail(Dataframe)
         Values codification
995  0.68623498        WC995
996  0.06631219        WC996
997  0.07788007        WC997
998  0.56687181        WC998
999  0.33394806        WC999
1000 0.04409823       WC1000

tail(Dataframe)
```